# How to read non ascii charactersin python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I know this could be a very common problem and there would be lots of solution already given. 
I am unable to find solution for my problem, can some one please let me know if there is any duplicate post, or how to fix it.

I need to read source data which has both ascii and non-ascii characters(need help in python2.7). After reading I need to do some comparison on the source data and then write it into a target file.

```
with open('read.txt', "r") as file:

    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    for lines in reader:
        LST_NM = (lines[0])
    print(LST_NM)
```

My Source File is :
read.txt

`"Abràmoff"`

With this non-ascii character, my code is giving below error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 266: ordinal not in range(128)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to determine what encoding was used to create your file.
For example, if your file was written using utf-8 then you can use something like this:

```
your_encoding = 'utf-8'
import codecs
f = codecs.open('read.txt', encoding=your_encoding)
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

Some other encodings you can try include 'cp1252' which is common on Windows and maybe 'latin_1'

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)